# Where do you find .NET app crash logs on linux?

Tags: linux, .net-core

On Windows, if a .NET app crashes, you can find a log entry in the system event viewer (eventvwr.msc) which records the fatal exception. Is there an equivalent under linux?

Comment: read up on syslog.

Comment: have you considered using a Logger? Serilog is a great logger.

Comment: @Neil a logger might not have the chance to log the exception which crashes your program

Comment: Hmm… why would it not?

Comment: @Neil, because when the process crashes inside the CLR, any managed code might not be executed anymore (including loggers).